# Is Operator inconsistent behaviour

Tags: vb.net

I have inconsistent behaviour of the VB Is Operator, as reproduced in a clean VB2012 Windows Executable project with code below. This makes it very difficult to debug some of my code, is this behaviour by design or is it a bug in VS/JIT?

**Problem Sumary**

At the breakpoint, Debug output show **True**, but Immediate Window command ?A Is B returns **False**

If I change ByRef to ByVal, the problem goes away

```
Public Sub Test()
    TestInner(Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub TestInner(ByRef A As Object)
    Dim B As Object

    B = New Object
    A = B

    Debug.WriteLine(A Is B)
    'Insert breakpoint here
End Sub
```

<s>I have what looks like a Compiler / Interpreter problem, has anyone seen this before?</s>

Note that this is a simplification of my (production code) problem.
If I run the exact code above, it returns True in both cases and works ok, but in my real world scenario, using fairly simple classs it fails as above.

I checked whether the classes I use have some sort of declaration problem or somehow override the Is Operator, but don't see anything weird about my classes.

I don't see how this could be anything other than a core .NET problem and am very confused!!

Comment: "If I run the exact code above, it returns True in both cases" - then you need to spend more time working on a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - asking us to *speculate* on how your real code is different from the above code, in such a way that you get different behaviour from your real code is pointless.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I've arrived at an MCVE and edited by question

Comment: Very interesting finding. I can reproduce this in VS2012 using the above example. The funny thing is that in ***Immediate Window***, `? A Is B` returns `False` but `? Object.ReferenceEquals(A,B)` returns `True`. `? A.GetHashCode() = B.GetHashCode()` returns `True`, too.

Comment: Confirmed in VS2012 and VS2013. Bug no longer present in VS2015 (RC).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever – you called it *bug*. If you have indices that this is really a bug, please add this as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @miroxlav - if/when I could find documentation on it I will.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever – you can add the answer anyway (*I believe this is a bug I can confirm in VS2012, VS2013 and which seems to be fixed in VS2015.*)  I think this answer is fair enough for not to be afraid of downvotes even without references. You have the checking work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is a bug, although I can't find any specific documentation about it.

The VB (and C#) expression evaluators have been extensively re-written for the VS2015 release and I would say that it's a bug in the older expression evaluator.

If we take your code and put it in a new console application in VS2015, `?A Is B` in the immediate window prints `True`. If, however, we change this setting:

[image: Expression Evaluators]
(Image from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx))

And then repeat the experiment, we do indeed get the behaviour you've observed and it prints `False`.